# Assets, rmagick and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rmagick

I am working on developing an app that will generate a digital card from the user. At the moment I am working on the rmagick code in a .rb file. Then just running it from the command line untill I figure it all out. I am having a few problems.

1. The source image I can't figure out the path to it. the only way I can get it to work is if I place it in the controllers directory with the cards.rb file. I want to have it in assets/cards/
2. Saving the file, same issue as above. I want to save it in assets/cards/@card_id.png
3. I'm trying to use a custom font in the assets/fonts/ dir I've tried self.font = “#{RAILS_ROOT}/assets/fonts/dreamorphansbd.ttf” but the code will not run. If I remove the quotes it runs but the font is not correct.
4. The last thing and I have yet to try it is adding the caption as the card.event from the db. I'm think it will along those line but not sure.

require 'RMagick'

```
include Magick

blank = Magick::Image.read("Blank-Card.png").first

text = Image.read("caption:Some big long text would go here.") do
  self.gravity = CenterGravity
  self.font = #{RAILS_ROOT}/app/assets/fonts/dreamorphansbd.ttf
  self.background_color= "Transparent"
  self.size = "638x"
  self.pointsize = 40
end

blank.composite!(text[0], CenterGravity, Magick::OverCompositeOp)

blank.write("card.png")
```

Comment: Hey have you make it work?

Answer (score 0):

1. try: Magick::Image.read(Rails.root.join('image', 'Blank-Card.png')).first
2. try: blank.write(Rails.root.join('image', 'card.png'))
3. With: Magick.fonts, you will see all available fonts
4. try: Image.read("caption:#{obj_active_record.your_attribute}")